# Compare DateTime objects in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I have a question about comparing dates set like that `$date=new DateTime($_GET['date']);`.

I know there is `$date1->diff($date2);` but this returns difference only.

This works fine when I made some tests:

```
$query='';
while ($date1 < $date2) {
  $query='...'.$date->format("Y-m-d").'...;';
  $date1->modify("+1 days");
}
$db->query($query);
```

My question: is that the right way of comparing 2 date objects? When I test it, results were ok, but is it possible I could get an error when script check `while` condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from PHP manual at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

> Changelog:
>
> Version: 5.2.2 Description: DateTime object comparison with the comparison operators changed to work as expected. Previously, all
> DateTime objects were considered equal (using ==).

So if you are using PHP 5.2.2 or superior, you must have no problems.